# php foreach is very slow

Tags: php, foreach, html-parsing, domdocument

i have this code which does the work exactly the way i want, it will tell me the all images available in any webpage but i takes more than one minute and the load on server also increases because of this piece of code.
if anyone knows better way(faster and less load on server) please give ur advice

```
     $html  = file_get_contents($link); 

    $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
     @$doc->loadHTML($html); 
    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img'); 


   foreach ($tags as $tag) { 
  $data = get_headers($tag->getAttribute('src'),1); 
    $op7=''.$tag->getAttribute('src').'';

  mysql_query ("INSERT INTO tablea (image) VALUES ('$op7')");


}
```

i have thought of using preg match but again thought it will not be good way to do.

Comment: how big is the web page in question, and just how many images are you talking about here?

Comment: @Spudley webpage is small and there are 5-10 images

Comment: you also have `get_headers` potentially for each tag, there is no restriction for it to be just image, which can be causing delays on hostname lookup and such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your performance problem will probably be due to `get_headers()`. This function makes an HTTP request to the specified URL.

You can prove this by writing a test program that simple does a sequence of `get_headers()` for the URLs in question, without a loop. eg:

```
<?php
get_headers('http://example.com/image1.png');
get_headers('http://example.com/image2.png');
get_headers('http://example.com/image3.png');
get_headers('http://example.com/image4.png');
get_headers('http://example.com/image5.png');
?>
```

My guess is that this simple program will take almost as long to run as your existing loop, which will prove that this is where your performance problem lies.

It's not clear why you're doing the `get_headers()` call at all; you haven't included any code that uses `$data`. If you can avoid doing this entirely, I would recommend it, because any call to an external URL is going to be slow; but doing it in a loop is going to be *really* slow.

Bear in mind that PHP won't load them as fast as a browser would because PHP be loading them serially -- one after the other, whereas the browser will load them in at the same time. Your PHP program will have to wait for the server to send its entire response before PHP can continue running the next line of your code. This means that the performance of your program is entirely dependant on the speed of the connection to the remote server. And that dependency is multiplied by the number of images. Not great; no wonder your program is slow.

Also, you're not allowing for image `src` attributes that are not a full URL. eg it might just be `/image5.png`, without the domain name. This will confuse `get_headers()`, and may make your program even slower.

In short, you should try to get rid of your dependency on `get_headers()`. If you can't get rid of it, maybe you could wrap it in some kind of local cache so that your program can check there first to see if it's loaded that file previously; that would at least save you having to make repeated duplicate calls over the network.

Hope that helps.

Off topic, but I feel I should point out a few other potential problems in your loop:

1. You are calling `$tag->getAttribute('src')` twice. This call isn't going to be a big performance issue, but since you're saving it to a variable (`$op7`), you may as well do that first, and then use `$op7` in the `get_headers()` call. This will save your program from having to make the duplicated method call. Small beans really, but even small stuff can add up when it's in a loop, and fixing it wouldn't make any difference to your functionality.
2. SQL injection issue with `$op7`. You need to escape it when using it as part of a SQL string. It's not clear from the code whether the HTML is from a trusted source. If it isn't, then it would be possible for someone who worked out what you were doing to write their page such that their image file name contain SQL code that could hack your site. Even if you do trust the page, your code doesn't allow for filenames to contain quotes.
3. The `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated. It is recommended to use the PDO library instead.
4. Be aware that on some servers, the `file_get_contents()` function may be disabled for use with external links.

Comment: i would like to salue to ur grt knowledge. u rocks

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out what is the really slowing down part. I guess it's the file_get_contents(), maybe the server the webpage lies on has bad upstream.

Comment: i  have tested file_get_contents alone for displaying entire webpage it is coming almost instantly

Comment: You can add something like `echo microtime();` at various place to see how long each section takes (if you subtract the previous "timestamp" :)

Comment: @ChristianGärtner nice idea i tested but found that it will execute few steps very fast after that it will not give any output and will keep on waiting after that that image output will come    0.48926000 1371386331
0.08764700 1371386332
0.68455400 1371386332
0.30316200 1371386333
0.91104800 1371386333
0.15009000 1371386335
0.74501600 1371386335
0.36565600 1371386336
0.02051100 1371386337
0.63640200 1371386337
0.23331700 1371386338
0.90688400 1371386338
0.68545900 1371386339
0.37058600 1371386340

Comment: Yeah. These numbers wont help us as long we do not know where you have placed the echos...

Comment: @ChristianGärtner just above insert

Comment: yeah, but where exactly, maybe post the updated code.